# Can't install the visual studio code C# extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, archlinux

things before I use Arch Linux, I installed the dotnet-runtime and the dotnet SDK befor

My extension bar in VSCode doesn't show the original C# extension instead it shows the one that muhammad-sammy made

and even when I click it the page that has the install button crashes and VSCode send me a message saying

"Unable to open 'Extension: C#': XHR failed."

and when I tried to install it with the terminal with the command
`code --install-extension ms-dotnettools.csharp`
it's just says

```
Installing extensions...
Extension 'ms-dotnettools.csharp' not found.
Make sure you use the full extension ID, including the publisher, e.g.: ms-dotnettools.csharp
Failed Installing Extensions: ms-dotnettools.csharp
```

Comment: Download the VISX from the GitHub releases: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.23.17

Answer (score 1):

Remove the VSCode from your computer and install the latest stable version. I had a similar problem recently and that fixed it for me.

Comment: where to get the stable version?

Comment: You can just google it as "vscode latest stable version" :D

The first link that pops up as I type this is: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_62

Comment: Remove it and google the **download vscode**  note: also maybe you have firewall issue

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I installed the pacman Version instead of the AUR -Real- Vresion and The pacman version is an open source one that doesn't include the extensions made for the proprietary version

in short just install it from the AUR or get it from the official website